# NHibernate: Table aliases in SqlProjection

Tags: nhibernate

I have the following code:

```
Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>("foo")
    .CreateAlias("foo.Bar", "bar")
    .SetProjections(Projections.SqlProjection("bar.FirstName + ' ' + bar.LastName));
```

The problem is with the alias for the bar table in the SqlProjection.

The Hibernate docs say that *"the string {alias} will be replaced by the alias of the root entity"*, but doesn't give any hint how you could access the aliases for non-root entities.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I has a similar question. Specifically, I wanted to create a projection which was a concatenation of several fields. Instead of using SqlProjection, I used:

```
Projections.SqlFunction("concat",
                        NHibernateUtil.String,
                        Projections.Property("Field"),
                        Projections.Constant(" "),
                        Projections.Property("Field2",
                        Projections.Constant(" "),
                        Projections.Property("Field3")
                    );
```

This is based on an NHibernate unit test: UsingSqlFunctions_Concat_WithCast. This works on SQL Server, despite "concat" not being a native function.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 Session.CreateCriteria<Foo>()
   .CreateCriteria("Bar")
      .SetProjections(Projections.SqlProjection("FirstName + ' ' + LastName)");
```